# limit of an expression involving a matrix as a parameter approaches infinity

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

X is a symmetric positive definite n by n matrix. This also means it is invertible of course. Consider the matrix Y, which is X, but with an extra row and column at the end: the first n rows of column n+1, and the first n columns of row n+1, are the n diagonals of X. The entry in row n+1, column n+1 of Y is some number T. I am interested in the limit as T approaches infinity of T*(row n+1, columns 1 through n of the inverse of Y). Is there a more utilitarian expression of this? Let's see if I can put this in latex:

$$X=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} & .... & x_{1n}\\
x_{12} & x_{22} & .... & x_{2n}\\
.... & .... & .... & .... \\
x_{1n} & x_{2n} & .... & x_{nn}\end{array} \right)$$
$$Y=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} & .... & x_{1n} & x_{11}\\
x_{12} & x_{22} & .... & x_{2n} & x_{22}\\
.... & .... & .... & .... & .... \\
x_{1n} & x_{2n} & .... & x_{nn} & x_{nn}\\
x_{11} & x_{22} & .... & x_{nn} & T\end{array} \right)$$
$$Z=Y^{-1}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
z_{11} & z_{12} & .... & z_{1,n+1}\\
z_{12} & z_{22} & .... & z_{2,n+1}\\
.... & .... & .... & .... \\
z_{1,n+1} & z_{2,n+2} & .... & z_{n+1,n+1}\end{array} \right)$$
And I want to know if there is a useful and simpler expression for:$$\lim_{T \to \infty}(T*[z_{1,n+1}, z_{2,n+1}, .... z_{n,n+1}])$$
PREFERABLY an expression that would not require me to simply approximate taking the limit by using a large value for T; that is what I am looking for, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $Y=\pmatrix{X&\mathbf{u}\\ \mathbf{u}^\top&T}$ and $Z=\pmatrix{\ast&\mathbf{v}\\ \mathbf{v}^\top&z_{n+1,n+1}}$, where the symbol $^\top$ denotes a transpose (not to be confused with the parameter $T$). Using [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we have $\mathbf{v}=-(X-\mathbf{u}\,T^{-1}\mathbf{u}^\top)^{-1}\mathbf{u}\,T^{-1}$.
Therefore
$$
\lim_{T\to\infty}T\mathbf{v}
=-\lim_{T\to\infty}(X-\mathbf{u}\,T^{-1}\mathbf{u}^\top)^{-1}\mathbf{u}
=-X^{-1}\mathbf{u}.
$$
In practice, however, it may take a very large $T$ for $T\mathbf{v}$ to approximate $-X^{-1}u$ accurately.

Comment: Ai yi yi, I should have used a different letter than T, I'm used to a tick mark/apostrophe being used to signify transpose, but fortunately it's obvious which T it is because of whether it's a superscript or not, and it's not in the final answer anyway. Seriously, though, is that it? It's so simple! I can't believe I missed that, I tried a bunch of things with actual numbers in matlab and I thought that was one of them and that it didn't work, but maybe I entered something in wrong. I'll have to try it again now to see if it works.

Comment: Holy cow, it works. Right down to the minus sign. Exactly as you say. I can't believe I didn't just stumble into something that simple just by trying random things, it seems like it ought to have been the very first thing one might randomly try.

Comment: @zortharg I did think of the possibility of confusing the transpose with the parameter $T$, but didn't expect that I did cause actual confusion. I'm sorry about that. After an edit, I hope it's clearer now.